# Group By Date Clusters

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a `login_log` table:
[image]

And I'm trying to build a query grouped "unique" logins baseed on `login_email, login_success, login_email, account_type_id, login_lock, login_ip`

So so far I have

```
SELECT count(*) count, MAX(login_date) date, login_ip, login_email, account_type_id, login_lock, login_success
FROM `login_log`
GROUP BY login_email, login_success, login_email, account_type_id, login_lock, login_ip
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Which gets me:
[image]

But take row 5 and 6 for example. On 6 the user failed the login 3 times before a successful one on row 5. Row 5's count should read 1 but it's grouping successful logins previous to the failed attempts.

What I want is one row with the successful login, a row with the failed login, then a row with a successful login, ordered by date.

How can I group the date query so that they don't "jump" each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you don't group by Date in the Group By section. As a result, your Count(*) increments unnecessarily.

Adding:

```
Group By Date
```

will work but might not give you the correct interval. Adding the MySQL Date() function would allow you to split it up by day, so you would add:

```
Group By Date(Date)
```

You also might want to change your alias Date to a non reserved MySQL keyword, like LogDate or something similar.

More on the MySQL Date/Time functions:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: If I group by date I might as well not group at all.  The idea is say, 3 failed login attempts all one after another would get grouped, but if a successful one happened in between, it would return 3 rows, count 2 => fail, count 1 => success, count 1 => fail

Comment: I see what you mean. Looks like you need an interval that changes with login_success. Not sure how to do this in pure MySQL. This might be a good start though: [link](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1280#798) - it tells you how to identify rows that differ from _immediately previous rows_ as you described above

Comment: using Date() is a quick, close-enough fix for now.